# Spark-shell returning the error : SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext/Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main

Tags: apache-spark, spark-shell

I tried installing Spark on windows 10. I followed the steps in this order:

1. Installed Java (outside Program Files folder in C drive)
2. Validated the version of spark downloaded from Apache(`spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz`)
3. unzip the spark in the folder outside Program files(Installed in C drive)
4. Downloaded `winutils.exe` (from GIT which is in the folder `Hadoop-3.2.0/bin`) and put that in `c:/hadoop/bin` folder
5. Set the environment variables for `JAVA_HOME` (path of java), `SPARK_HOME` (path of the spark installation), `HADOOP_HOME` (path of winutils)
6. Included the `PATH` variable with `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` and similarly the other 2.

When I tried running Spark -version, it gives an error `Spark is not recognized as the internal or external command`. When I run `spark-shell`, it gives the error `SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext / Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main /  ERROR Main: Failed to initialize Spark session.`

Could you please let me know if I missed any steps for successful execution? Any suggestions on how to resolve these errors while running spark?

Comment: Have you checked that your version of Java is compatible?

Comment: Thanks! I installed Java 8 version earlier but I updated the java Version to 17 and now I  do not see the above error and the Spark shell starts. But with these errors.  "module java. base does not export sun.nio.ch to the unnamed module " and import spark.implicits._ - Value spark not found.